# Nested Loop efficiency Python

Tags: python

```
def sum67(nums):
  for i in range(0, len(nums)): 
    print nums[i]
    if nums[i] == 6:
      nums[i] = 0
      for j in range(i+1, len(nums)):
        print nums[j]
        temp = nums[j]
        nums[j] = 0
        if temp == 7: break
      i=j+1
  return sum(nums)
```

I am summing all numbers in a list apart from those between a direct 6 - 7 block. My code works fine but I'm confused about why the first loop is seemingly resetting even when I set i=j+1.

I wanted to 'skip' doing the first if statement on all the j's that went through the second 'for' block because there's no point checking whether 0=6.
I thought putting i=j+1 would achieve that but the print nums[i] statement is still printing out the 0's corresponding to those that went through the second 'for' block. That suggests that the loop is continuing from where it left off rather than from j+1.

For example, sum67([2, 7, 6, 2, 6, 7, 2, 7]) is printing out 3 zeroes corresponding to 2,6,7. So why isn't the loop continuing from j+1?

Thanks

Comment: i gets set at the beginning of each loop, so i=j+1 does nothing. As for solving your problem I advise rewording the question to explain what you are actually trying to achieve as it's not clear.

Comment: @andyhasit  So how would I make the outer loop continue from i=j+1 in order to increase efficiency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you were looking for:

```
def sum67(nums):
    include_next = True
    included_nums = []
    for i in nums:
        if include_next and i not in (6, 7):
            included_nums.append(i)
        if i == 6:
            include_next = False
        if i == 7:
            include_next = True
    return sum(included_nums)
```

It seems you were over complicating things. Don't be afraid to create new variables to track state as these can make the code clearer, provided you give them names which explain what their purpose is (which you should always do). It's also usually a very bad idea to modify a list while looping over it.

An even neater solution would be to create a reusable function, now your function has a name which explains its purpose (which you should also always do):

```
def sum_excluding(nums, start, end):
    include_next = True
    included_nums = []
    for i in nums:
        if include_next and i not in (start, end):
            included_nums.append(i)
        if i == start:
            include_next = False
        if i == end:
            include_next = True
    return sum(included_nums)

def sum_excluding_6_to_7(nums):
    return sum_excluding(nums, 6, 7)
```

Comment: Thanks very much. A very elegant solution, and nicely generalised. Do you know where I can learn python and get challenges post codecademy and codingbat? I am currently going through the python documentation

Comment: I have my own training portal. Go to codecoaching.ninja and use the contact form to say hi. I'll sign you up for a free account.

Comment: Thanks very much; I did as you said.